# JQuery: how to make a list of words in html element <b></b>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given a HTML DOM element with `b` elements such :

```
<div>
  My <b>text</b> have some <b>words</b> or <b>groups of words</b> in <b>bold</b>. How to do a variable <b>list</b> with these texts ?
</div>
```

Given we attack this with JS or JQuery.

How to get the list of all **bold words**, something like such :

```
var list = [ "text", "have some ", "words", "groups of words", "in","bold", "list" ,...];
```

I tried `.text()` and `.html()` but it doesn't work, see http://jsfiddle.net/LF5dX/1/

JSfiddle demo appreciate since more relevant for all future readers / users.

Comment: use a wrapper div if you can

Answer (score 5):

You can use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map) along with [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text) and [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/)

```
var list = $('div b').map(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text());
}).get()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/RAbtK/)

Comment: @Hugolpz `.map()` returns jQuery wrapper object, `.get()` will extract an array from that jQuery wrapper object

Comment: @ArunPJohny it is worth to mention : an array which will contain DOM elements and not jQuery elements

Comment: For completeness sake: li-items should, as far as I know, be a part of a list. Therefore, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/RAbtK/2/) might be a better showcase.

Comment: @ArunPJohny: thanks for the trim(), not asked, but witty addition !

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
var arr=[];
$('div b').each(function(){
    arr.push($(this).text());
});
console.log(arr);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kZHyu/)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Oh, ok, I see OP has edited the answer, so this answer is no longer on-topic. Leaving it here though.

Not sure how you'd do it in jQuery, but here's how to do it in plain JavaScript:

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
var textContents = [].map.call(div.childNodes, function(node) {
    return node.textContent.trim();
});
console.log(textContents);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RGaQp/1/